# Record Audio with frequencies below 100 Hz or 10 Hz in Android

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, android-emulator, record

We are developing an android application that requires recording of sound on the full sound spectrum (linear between 10Hz and 10Khz).
In our mobile application the content of the audio signal below 100Hz is critically important.

So we have a few questions

**Are android phones capable to capture the audio signal below 100hz or 10hz?**

**Is there any way where we can input a 10hz audio signal as an input into the emulator of AndroidStudio?**

Comment: _Are android phones capable to capture the audio signal below 100hz or 10hz?_ **A: Yes**